# Showing Dialog in the current Activity

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm writing a game. When user ends level, these things happen:

1. Send a POST, to check if the level record was beaten. (1-5 seconds)
2. If it was so, show a `Dialog` "enter your name". (fast)
3. When user clicks OK, send a POST with his record. (1-5 seconds)

When user ends level he is in the `GameActivity`. `checkWorldRecord()` is called, and in it, an `AsyncTask` is started:

```
private void checkWorldRecord(final RecordType recordType, final double time, final int level)
{
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            new DownloadTask(recordType, time, level).execute();
        }
    });
}
```

`DownloadTask` is doing these 3 things, which I listed at the beginning:

```
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    RecordType recordType;
    double time;
    int level;

    public DownloadTask(RecordType recordType, double time, int level)
    {
        super();
        this.recordType = recordType;
        this.time = time;
        this.level = level;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Network.isWorldRecord(recordType, time, level)) // 1.
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Dialogs.showEnterNameAndSend(GameActivity.this, recordType, time, level, highScores.getGamesPlayed(),
                highScores.getStars()); // 2.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, when the user waits after the game, if he stays in the `GameActivity`.

**The problem is, when:**

1. User ended the game. `checkWorldRecord()` is called.
2. In separate thread the 1st POST starts.
3. User presses back button and changes activity to another, to `MainActivity`.
4. `AsyncTask` finished checking, we have new record. `showEnterNameAndSend()` wants to first build and later display `AlertDialog`. BOOM. Because we were passing `GameActivity`, and now `MainActivity` is on the top:

---

```
public static void showEnterNameAndSend(final Activity activity, final RecordType recordType, final double time,
        final int level, final long gamesPlayed, final int stars)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity); // BOOM!!!
    final EditText editText = new EditText(activity);
    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]
    { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(Const.MAX_NAME_LENGTH) });
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    builder.setView(editText);
    builder.setTitle(recordType + " world record!");
    builder.setMessage("Enter your name:");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
            String username = editText.getText().toString();
            if (username.equals(""))
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                Network.sendRecord(recordType, username, time, level, gamesPlayed, stars); // 3.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                showInternetError(activity);
            }
        }
    });
    showDialogOnUiThread(activity, builder);
}

private static void showDialogOnUiThread(Activity activity, final AlertDialog.Builder builder)
{
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            builder.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Yes, I also prefer passing `Context`, instead of whole `Activity` to `showEnterNameAndSend()`. But, `showDialogOnUiThread()` (which is called by `showEnterNameAndSend()`) requires `Activity`, to show the `Dialog` on UI thread, with `activity.runOnUiThread()`.

**How to repair this?** Maybe for example there is some method `getCurrentActivity()`, so I don't have to pass an `Activity`, which can be already hidden? If I can somehow cancel showing the dialog, after the user closes `GameActivity`, it will be also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to prevent crashing your app by trying to show that dialog, you could've solve that by setting a flag:

```
public static boolean userIsOut = false;
```

and then set it to true when user is out of that activity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    userIsOut = true;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

In your ShowEnterNameAndSend() method, you can do like:

```
if(!userIsOut)
    showDialogOnUiThread(activity, builder);
```

So if user's out of that activity, the dialog will never be built.

But if you insist on showing dialog, then i guess you should write your own getCurrentActivity() method. To achieve that, you can have a class to hold that variable

```
public static class ActivityHolder {
     public static Activity current;

     public static void setCurrentActivity(Activity act) {
           current = act;
     }

     public static Activity getCurrentActivity() {
           return current;
     }
}
```

And you should set this current activity on every activity's onResume, and onCreate methods... So you'll always know which activity you're at, and you can use that activity to show dialog.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ActivityHolder.setCurrentActivity(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that I got on my mind:

The first one is to create an activty (lets call it SpecialActivity).

This activity will hold a broadcast receiver that will be registered in onResume, and will be unregistered in onPause.

each one of your activities will inherit SpecialActivity and will get broadcast from doInBackground method, and then will call the method for showing the dialog.

The second, is to create an INVISIBLE activity (lets call it DialogActivity) that
its only responsibility is to call the dialog in onCreate, and to kill itself once the
dialog has been dissmissed.
that activity will also be triggered from doInBackground (startActivity...).

Maybe there are more simple and smart solutions, but that's what I got on my mind :D

Answer (score 0):

Try just changing the context on the dialog to the application context instead of the activity context. you can get it by using a custom application class (my preference) that holds a static reference to the application context or use GameActivity.this.getAppContext()

Comment: But I need to run builder.show() on the UI thread. To do so, I must use runOnUiThread(), which is a method of Activity, not Context.

Comment: I don't think the context matters in most cases. You should be able to create the builder using the application context and call show on the UI thread just fine. Have you tried that?

Comment: If I remove runOnUiThread() app crashes. So, how can I run builder.show() without the reference to Activity?

Comment: I never said remove the runOnUiThread() call. But you can create the builder in a runnable passed to runOnUiThread() and show it in there and it should work.